# Windows keeps forgetting my sd card should be shared

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-sharing

I've got an sd card slot in my Windows 7 laptop. I always use the same sd card in it, and I assigned the drive letter Z to it.

I set it to share, with permissions to Everyone to edit files, which is important to me. That way I can upload files from another computer.

My problem: Windows sometimes forgets that the drive is shared, after the sd card has been out of the computer and back in. It doesn't happen all the time, just sometimes, and then it's annoying because I have to redefine the sharing and permissions.

Any way to make Windows remember my sharing settings? Or alternatively, a scripted way to reenable sharing so I wouldn't have to go through the GUI?

Comment: Are you properly ejecting the SD card through the "safe remove hardware" feature before ejecting it?

Comment: I'm way too cool to be doing that.

Comment: You're not safely removing the hardware, windows alters the state of the drive, and you're wondering why? tss.. tss.. tss..

Answer (score 3):

#### Or alternatively, a scripted way to re-enable sharing?

You can use the following command:

```
net share sharename z:\
```

where `sharename` is the name you want the drive to be known as.

For example:

```
net share MySDCard z:\
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [net share / net view / net session / net file / net use - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/net-share.html)